# How to properly set entity update time with Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping

Column in MySQL table is called "updated_at".
It's of datetime type, not null.
Doctine type is datetime as well.

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Some\Bundle\Entity\Example:
    type:            entity
    table:           examples
    fields:
        id:
            id:     true
            type:   integer
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        ...
        createdAt:
            type:   datetime
            column: created_at
        updatedAt:
            type:   datetime
            column: updated_at

$e = new Example;
$e->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime);
$em->persist($e);
/* after this I need $e->updatedAt to be MySQL's default 0 (0000-00-00) */
$em->flush();
/* but it will throw 
"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'updated_at' cannot be null" 
if I won't set it in Example::__contruct() 
which I don't see any reason to do 
apart from complying with Doctrine shortcomings. */
```

If entity wasn't ever updated after it was created I don't want to have any value in this column.

How to skip this column or set proper value upon persist without changing MySQL or Doctrine types (because they are right)?

Comment: Are you using [Timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) of the DoctrineExtensions?

Comment: I use Symfony2.2 with doctrine ORM and doctrine bundle.

Comment: Yes, but which bundle gives you the Timestamable behavior? [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle)?

Comment: There is no behavior. All is set "manually".

Comment: Then, show some code!

Comment: I would suggest you check out the [Timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) behavoir which Pazi allready mentioned. Takes 2 minutes to implement and does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine cannot skip columns, uses all fields which you defined in metadata config.

You should set some default value in constructor, empty string suits well for almost all types.

It will be used just once upon persist, subsequent fetches won't trigger construct.

Answer (score 2):

Two options. Use the [Timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) as i mentioned in the comments. For symfony it's integrated in the [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). Then you simply add it to your mapping yaml and no further code in controllers, services, etc. is required.

Option two: Set the `updated_at` to NULL instead of NOT NULL. NOT NULL means, there must be a value (eg 0000-00-00 at least). If you allow a NULL value in MySQL, you will reach what you consider.